# How do I get the current "camera position" in PyMol so I can reuse it in scripts?

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, structural-biology, pymol

I have a few protein models I want to take pictures of with various ligands bound.  It would be nice if I could do it from the same "position", but the only way I can figure out to repeat the same view is with `zoom resi. 64, 152, 150` or the like, which isn't framed that well.

How can I manually position the viewport, capture it's parameters, and repeat it in the script?

---

I have found **get_view**, e.g.

```
PyMOL>get_view
### cut below here and paste into script ###
set_view (\
     0.590180993,    0.670941532,    0.448923886,\
    -0.507570565,    0.740831316,   -0.439937204,\
    -0.627747774,    0.031782545,    0.777776182,\
     0.000000000,    0.000000000, -417.497009277,\
     0.741809845,    7.078243256,   16.473480225,\
   329.157806396,  505.836212158,  -20.000000000 )
### cut above here and paste into script ###
```

but this doesn't work in a `.py` script, where I need to modify it to `cmd.set_view(...)`, as it complains it wants just (or up to 5) arguments, not 18.  [The wiki is vague about it](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Set_View), it just says

> #### PYMOL API
>
> ```
> cmd.set_view(string-or-sequence view)
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to pass the matrix as a String containing 18 floats separated by commas, e.g. like

```
cmd.set_view ('''
     0.590180993,    0.670941532,    0.448923886,\
    -0.507570565,    0.740831316,   -0.439937204,\
    -0.627747774,    0.031782545,    0.777776182,\
     0.000000000,    0.000000000, -417.497009277,\
     0.741809845,    7.078243256,   16.473480225,\
   329.157806396,  505.836212158,  -20.000000000 ''')
```

`cmd.get_view()` seems to return a tuple, so you'll have to convert that to a String if you want to pass the same position to `cmd.set_view()`.

I tried it in Pymol 1.3 on the command line (not in a script though) and it seemed to work.

Comment: Ah, I guess if I translated the "command line/interactive form" of the commands into the API version, I should have also kept those parenthesis that `get_view` returns so they're really nested (so you do pass it a tuple).  Would look like `cmd.set_view((1,2,3...))`

Comment: Note that you might also want to make use of `get_viewport` and `viewport` in case you do not only need the same perspective, but also the same paddings to the outer boundary.

Comment: I should add that `get_view` seems to be undocumented at the moment. It works for me with PyMOL 1.5. Looks like this or a related command does not work reliably in all situations. You might also want to read https://www.mail-archive.com/pymol-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg08419.html