# Turn off multithreading in pymol

Tags: bioinformatics, pymol

By default, `pymol` seems to grab the number of cores on the system for rendering. How can I force it to only use one core?

**Motivation:**

I have a large collection time-series of of coordinate data from a computational protein folding experiment. I'd like batch render the generated pdb files into a movie in a programmatic way. Pymol however likes to eat up as many cores as it finds available. I'd like to retain some control of the computational burden (required for some computational cluster jobs). How can I force pymol to only use one (or n) core(s)?

**Solution:**

While the question was closed (as it was decided to not fit into biological criteria of the site) future visitors might find it useful to know the answer:

```
set max_threads, 1
```

The solution was found in a [Biostars question](http://biostars.org/post/show/44065/turn-off-multithreading-in-pymol).

Comment: I'm all for bioinformatics questions, but this one has absolutely no biological component to it.

Comment: @DanielStandage I'm sorry, and I'll happily move the question somewhere else. I don't think this belongs on SO, however. Do you have a good suggestion where?

Comment: @DanielStandage I only posted this question since I saw a high voted question here on pymol scripting: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/732/822 Again let me know if this is not the intention of the site.

Comment: Try http://www.biostars.org/.

Comment: I think bioinformatics questions can definitely be on-topic for this site, assuming they include a significant biological component (or at least some biological component). The question you refer to includes as least a minimal description of a biological question being addressed, whereas this one focuses entirely on the software aspect.

Comment: @DanielStandage I've given some motivation for the question. I think that the question in general might be useful for others working with pymol scripts, so I'm going to leave it up. If the community decides to close, I'll understand.

Comment: @Danielstandage, lets take this to the meta.

Comment: @Hooked - what platform are you running? Linux?

Comment: @Luke Yes, this is on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Though I think the clusters run on a non-Debian distribution.

Comment: @DanielStandage So on the (fictional) Builders.SE site, "How do I fix my circular saw?" should be closed because it's not about building anything?

Comment: @NickT It would depend on what the scope of the Builders.SE site was, as per their FAQ. [Our FAQ](http://biology.stackexchange.com/faq) states: "Questions on interdisciplinary subjects like bioinformatics are also welcome, as long as they focus on the biological part of the subject."